# Button with label is not visible when system calls a funtion from another python file

Tags: python, tkinter

i have 2 python file TestBtnImage1.py and TestBtnImage2.py

I am trying to call display() fucntion of TestBtnImage2 on button click of TestBtnImage1.py,
button without image displying in frame, however button with image is not displying.
thanks in advance

TestBtnImage1.py

```
from tkinter import *
from TestBtnImage1 import *

frame = Tk()
frame.title("TextBox Input")
frame.geometry('200*200')
frame.config(background="blue")

printButton = Button(frame, text="click me", command=display()).place(x=50, y=50)
frame.mainloop()
```

TestBtnImage2.py

```
from tkinter import *


def display():
    frame = Tk()
    frame.title("TextBox Input")
    frame.geometry('200*200')
    frame.config(background="blue")

    logo1 = PhotoImage(file="cheta.png")
    Button(gui, text="click me", image=logo1, bg="blue",  relief=FLAT).place(x=100, y=200)

    frame.mainloop()
```

tried googling for the same issue also stackoverflow but no help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: First `command=display()` will execute `display()` immediately without clicking the button.  `command=display` should be used instead.  Second don't create more than one instance of `Tk()`, use `Toplevel()` for windows other than the root window. Also run `.mainloop()` only once.  The image issue is the same as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function).

Comment: As I can see in `TestBtnImage1.py`, you are importing itself (`from TestBtnImage1 import *`). It should be `from TestBtnImage2 import *`, right? Also, @acw1668 has already explained, use `command=display` instead of `display()`...

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems in your code.

##### In TestBtnImage1.py

- You are importing itself, which will cause a NameError.
  `from TestBtnImage1 import *`
  and you just need to change it to `TestBtnImage2`
- The geometry specifier should be 'x'
  If you use `frame.geometry('200*200')`, it will cause tkinter bad geometry specifier error.
  So use `200x200` instead of `200*200`.
- The button command
  `printButton = Button(frame, text="click me", command=display()).place(x=50, y=50)`
  The `display()` function will automatically run when executed. You can remove the brackets `()`
  -> `printButton = Button(frame, text="click me", command=display).place(x=50, y=50)`

(*) Also, the `printButton` (`None`) does nothing. So you can remove it.

##### In TestBtnImage2.py

- Use `Toplevel()` instead of a new `Tk()`
  -> `frame = Toplevel()`
- Again, bad geometry specifier.
  -> `frame.geometry('200x200')`
- Use `mainloop()` only once.
  You can remove `frame.mainloop()` at the end of the function

(*) Also,
`Button(gui, text="click me", image=logo1, bg="blue",  relief=FLAT).place(x=100, y=200)`
The master `gui` is not defined.

So, **the full code should be:**
`TestBtnImage1.py`:

```
from tkinter import *
from TestBtnImage2 import *

frame = Tk()
frame.title("TextBox Input")
frame.geometry('200x200')
frame.config(background="blue")

Button(frame, text="click me", command=display).place(x=50, y=50)
frame.mainloop()
```

`TestBtnImage2.py`:

```
from tkinter import *


def display():
    frame = Toplevel()
    frame.title("TextBox Input")
    frame.geometry('200x200')
    frame.config(background="blue")

    logo1 = PhotoImage(file="cheta.png")
    Button(frame, text="click me", image=logo1, bg="blue",  relief=FLAT).place(x=100, y=200)
```